# Add ajax-fetched data to dynamically added elements with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to add ajax-fetched data into elements which are dynamically added to the DOM with jquery. The elements have the same class but different IDs. They are added by 'click' events. Some advice me how I can do that. My problem now is that every time I click on list to add the element, it fetches data that is not associated with that ID.
The list HTML looks like this:

```
<li id="23" class="options">Item 23</li> 
<li id="24" class="options">Item 24</li>
<li id="25" class="options">Item 25</li>
```

This is my js:

```
var box = '<div class="box" id="{0}"><div class="box-content"></div></div>';
//how to add the box to the DOM
$('li.options').click(function(){
  id = $(this).attr('id');
  $(boxes).append(box.format(id));
  //Fetching data via ajax
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'fetch.php',
     dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,
     data: {'id' : id},
     success: function(res){
        $(this).find('box-content').append(res);
     }
  });
});
```

Everything is working fine up to this point. Elements are being appended correctly. If I click on 'List 23', 'box id 23' is appended. Same thing for list 24 and 25. (Boxes are being appended correctly with their corresponding IDs). My problem is when fetching data. If I click on list 23, data for 23 is correctly appended on box 24 but when I click on list 24, even the data that had been fetched for list 23 is appended. (23 is still open). So I end up have like 'double data' on the box that is appended 2nd, 'tripple data' for the box that is appended third ... et cetera.

Anyone with any idea on how I can solve this?
I thought of getting the ajax out of the click event but I don't know which event I can use to fire it. However, I am open to any suggestions on how I could solve this. I have been having the problem for months now. Any idea is welcome

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `empty()` the box contents before adding the content?  The question is slightly unclear.  Can you create a functional sample?

Comment: Thank you. This has worked. But again, data for the last appended box is appended to all boxes. Any idea on how I could solve this?

Comment: I think your class selector 'box-content' might be to vague. Depending on the HTML structure the $.find() function can return multiple DOM elements. Seems like you are appending the results to more then one 'box-content' without meaning to.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make ajax requests in jsfiddle, but here is an example of what I am saying 
https://jsfiddle.net/pkgf7enj/10/
Assume the response is 23 for list 23, 24 for list 24, 25 for list 25, now the boxes will take the data for the last clicked item. Example, when I click on box 23 first, it will take 23, when I click on 25 after that, both boxes will have 25 on them

Comment: I am still unclear about what your desired functionality is.  Do you want a new box everytime you click a list item?  Do you want the previous clicked box still visible?  Or do you want to reuse one box over and over?

Comment: Yes. Assume that the data that ajax returns is equal to the ID. So if i click on item 1, the data that ajax returns is 1, if I click on 2 it returns 2 etc.
The problem is once I click on item 1, the 1 is appended to the box-content, thats alright. Now if I click on item 2, I have 2 boxes open, but both have the value of the last clicked item (in this case, 2). If I click on item 3, all the 3 boxes will have 3. 
I want every box to have its own value consistent with the id supplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I changed in your javascript.  You can see I only append the box once and only once for each `id`.  I then just replaced the AJAX with a single call to set the content to the `id` for an example.

It is my understanding that this is what you are after.

```
$('li.options').click(function() {
  id = $(this).attr('id');
  if($("#" + id + ".box").length <= 0){
      $('.boxes').append('<div class="box" id="'+id+'"><div class="box-content"></div></div>');
  //Fetching data via ajax
      $("#" + id + ".box > .box-content").html(id);
}});
```

Here is the updated fiddle.  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkgf7enj/13/)

Comment: This is very helpful. But when you use ajax, it will give different results

Comment: unless there is something wrong with your AJAX, I would just put the line I have in the success function.

Comment: The logic is, everytime you click on an item, say item id 1, the ajax call will be that of id 1, if you click on item 2 the ajax call will be for id 2. The ajax is ok. It is bringing back all the data. Only that when you click all boxes, they will not have data associated with their ids but the id of the last item. Using  $("#" + id + ".box > .box-content") ..., the other boxes remain empty and the last one is filled

Comment: This code ideally will not run your ajax more than once for each list-item.  When you click each one you get a box and the ajax fills that box.  when you click a link a second time nothing happens.  The boxes never go away and are never refilled or emptied...